# Can't .delegate properly a slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates, slideshow

problem page: www.hovaness.com/work
I have a function with variable name sliderun(); that runs a slide show on the page. I have buttons with id #KIWCK1, #kiwck2, etc.. that load external HTML to replace the content within the slideshow. This is my code.

```
jQuery("#kwick2").click(function () {
jQuery('#photography').load('/design.html #design');
jQuery("body").delegate('#photography', "click", sliderun); 
});
```

Now when i click #KWICK2 the new images load just fine, except they don't get the jQuery slideshow script like when you load the page, it only gains the sliderun attributes when you click on the element and photos themselves, how would i tell the new content loaded to take in sliderun script and events when I click the #KWICK2 button not the images themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change to load function to this:

```
jQuery("#kwick2").click(function () {
    jQuery('#photography').load('/design.html #design', function() {
         jQuery("body").delegate('#photography', "click", sliderun); 
    });
});
```

maybe it's because the data still didn't load, this way the delegate will take place after the data was loaded